# TYPO3 Realurl 404 Not Found error

Tags: .htaccess, typo3, typo3-7.6.x, realurl

I'm working around with **TYPO3 7.6.7 and realurl 2.0.14** . Currently I'm stuck up with the following trouble. I configured realurl manually and after enabling realurl I'm getting **404 Not found** error.
I've read number of questions here itself, regarding the same issue. But unfortunately I'm still in the maze. Few of the solutions were restarting apache, cross checking 'rewrite mode on' in .htaccess and clearing cache(I seriously don't think so). The point is there isn't any answer explaining what the real problem is.
To my wonder, realurl generated url is as it is supposed to be.
Really desperate enough to try any possible solution.

Comment: Is the 404 error from TYPO3 or apache? Also does it work if you request the pages with id=5 and similar parameters?

Comment: @JozefSpisiak Without realurl and with parameters the redirects are working fine I think.

Comment: Realurl doesn't disable the parameters, so try with realurl, but use the parameters (construct the URL manually, not by clicking on links). Also 404 error is from TYPO3 or apache?

Comment: It might be an apache error. Because I've tried by altering the rewrite mode in .htaccess and got the same result. Well can it be like .htaccess is inaccessible,invisible or some thing like that ??

Comment: Check your htaccess for allowoverride value: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In quite some cases this was caused by a cHash mismatch. Usually the Install Tool setting `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['pageNotFoundOnCHashError']` is set to 1 which triggers the 404.
The 404 is intended behaviour, because a cHash mismatch usually indicates that URL parameters are manipulated.

I haven't tracked down the cause of the error in all cases. In a few cases pw_comments added parameters to the URL; in these cases it was enough to add the parameters to the list of parameters which need to be excluded for cHash calculations. In other cases it might be a bug in RealURL (since everything works without RealURL active).

Answer (score 0):

A 404 can also be caused if realUrl can't detect a base URL.
Check if `config.baseURL` or `config.absrefprefix` is set.

Answer (score 0):

First add This two lines in your setup.txt

```
config.simulateStaticDocuments = 0
config.tx_realurl_enable = 1
```

After check `mod_rewrite` is active or not. if not active then active first.

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo service apache2 restart
```

All settings are comlated but stil realurl not working then open this file `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` and check your host path is correct or not. if not correct then change your path and restart your server.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Directory /var/www/html>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
    </Directory> 
    .....
    .....

</VirtualHost>
```